# Connect to EKS cluster using python and eks-token. (no kube-config)

Tags: python, authentication, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want to consume kubernetes API to get information from an EKS cluster.

Right now I am using kubeconfig to connect to the cluster and here is my code:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
import json
from jsonpath_ng import parse

kube_config = os.getcwd() + "/kube_config"
config.load_kube_config(kube_config)


    def get_result():
        """
        """
        res = {}
    
        res["ds_name"] = get_ds()
        res["deploy_name"] = get_deployments()
        #resjson = selfish(json.dumps(res))
    
        resjson = {
            'self' : json.dumps(res,indent=2)
        }
        print(json.dumps(res,indent=2))
        print(res)
        print(resjson)
    
    
    
    def get_ds():
            """
            Get list of DaemonSets
            """
            res = {}
            v1 = client.AppsV1Api()
            ret = v1.list_daemon_set_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
            list_ds = []
            for i in ret.items:
                item = "%s" % (i.metadata.name)
                list_ds.append(item)
            return list_ds
```

kubeconfig contains certificate-authority-dat, EKS cluster endpoint and clustername. I want to find a way to connect to kubernetes cluster which is more secure than this. I can get an eks-token through python using following code:

```
from eks_token import get_token
from pprint import pprint

response = get_token(cluster_name='xxxx')
pprint(response)
```

but I am not sure how to use this token in my python script to authenticate with kubernetes cluster to get the information I need from kubernetes cluster.

Can someone help me with the code or documentation on how to use eks-token in an python program to connect to a EKS cluster to run interact with kubernetes API using python ?

Comment: You want to use AWS EKS [get-token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/get-token.html) API, is that correct? If so, the awscli command to retrieve that temporary token can be specified in kubeconfig and executed by the client. But you'll have to ship awscli with your application. This is actually the default way it works with EKS, if you are created the cluster and got the initial kubeconfig.

Comment: I am already getting the token with "eks_token" library. I don't have to use awscli. AWS already thought about this and gave us a way without using awscli. my question here is after getting token, how can I use it in kubeconfig ?

Comment: Sorry, never used that library myself and missed the point. There is a `config.load_kube_config_from_dict()` function, which accepts kubeconfig in dict format. You can inject the token there and call the function.  Aside from that I know no other way.